# Having multiple mat-button-toggle-groups on one page

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I have several button groups but they all seem to be sharing the same values across each other. It seems that it's because they're all assigned to the same #group but if I try to assign them to anything other than their current group I get an error.

```
<div class="options">
            <span class="option-left">
                <mat-button-toggle-group #group="matButtonToggleGroup" aria-label="Font Style" [(value)]="TableType" (change)="OnToggleChanged(group.value)">
                    <mat-button-toggle value="Trader">Trader</mat-button-toggle>
                    <mat-button-toggle value="Source">Source</mat-button-toggle>
                    <mat-button-toggle value="Shift">Shift</mat-button-toggle>
                    <mat-button-toggle value="Product">Product</mat-button-toggle>
                    <mat-button-toggle value="RiskLevel">Risk</mat-button-toggle>
                </mat-button-toggle-group>
            </span>
            <span>
                <mat-button-toggle-group #group="matButtonToggleGroup" aria-label="Font Style" [(value)]="TradeViewMode">
                    <mat-button-toggle (click)="ViewTrades()" value="Show">View Trades</mat-button-toggle>
                    <mat-button-toggle (click)="HideTrades()" value="Hide">Hide Trades</mat-button-toggle>
                </mat-button-toggle-group>
            </span>
            <span class="option-right">
                <mat-button-toggle-group #group="matButtonToggleGroup" aria-label="Font Style" [(value)]="NumberType" (change)="NumberTypeValueChanged(group.value)">
                    <mat-button-toggle value="percent">Percent</mat-button-toggle>
                    <mat-button-toggle value="currency">Dollars</mat-button-toggle>
                </mat-button-toggle-group>
            </span>
        </div>
```

Additionally I have an issue with the (change) event

```
public OnToggleChanged() {
        this.PieChartSource = this.CollectionByType[this.TableType];
        this.EndTime = this.GetEndTIme();

        if (this.TableType != 'Trader' && this.TableType != 'Source') {
            this.ViewTradesEnabled = false;
            this.TradeViewMode = 'Hide';
        }

        this.GetSlippage();
    }
```

In the function above this.TableType is undefined which I'm not understanding since the toggle should have set it to the selected value.

Comment: " their current group I get an error", well, whats the error?

Comment: It was that it couldn't find the group I changed it to. But I'm no longer using groups based on your answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have a working [example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1lztv4-gz3yqb).** Take a look at the console logs to see how group.value works.

The name of the mat-button-toggle-group does not matter with respect to the value changes. All that should matter is that each group is bound to a different variable. Also, give each group its own id. They cant all be "#group"

**Like so:**

```
<mat-button-toggle-group #group="matButtonToggleGroup" aria-label="Table Type" [(value)]="TableType" (change)="OnToggleChanged(group.value)">
  <mat-button-toggle value="Trader">Trader</mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle value="Source">Source</mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle value="Shift">Shift</mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle value="Product">Product</mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle value="RiskLevel">Risk</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
<br>
<br>
<mat-button-toggle-group #group2="matButtonToggleGroup" aria-label="Trade View" [(value)]="TradeViewMode" (change)="OnToggleChanged(group2.value)">
  <mat-button-toggle (click)="ViewTrades()" value="Show">View Trades</mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle (click)="HideTrades()" value="Hide">Hide Trades</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
<br>
<br>
<mat-button-toggle-group #group3="matButtonToggleGroup" aria-label="Number Type" [(value)]="NumberType" (change)="OnToggleChanged(group3.value)">
  <mat-button-toggle value="percent">Percent</mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle value="currency">Dollars</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>

<pre>
  TableType: {{TableType}}
  TradeViewMode: {{TradeViewMode}}
  NumberType: {{NumberType}}
</pre>
```

Comment: Awesome thanks. Is there another way other than (change) to do component processing after a toggle changes?

Comment: You'll have to elaborate on what you mean by component processing. But if you want to trigger changes within that same component upon toggle clicks, then the (change) event is your friend.

Comment: I just updated the original post with what I'm talking about. this.TableType is undefined in the (change) event

Comment: I see. In that case go ahead and through the groups back in there. Your issue was that all your groups were the same id. Im updating my answer with a new stackblitz